# Get median from number series using Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, math, apache-commons, median

Using Apache Commons Math, how do I get the median from a series of numbers?

The [Commons Math User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html) says `DescriptiveStatistics` supports median, yet the [JavaDocs for DescriptiveStatistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html) makes no mention of it. It does mention geometric mean, is this the same thing as median?

I do see `getPercentile(double)`. Is `getPercentile(50)` the same as median?

Comment: The median is the number in the middle in sorted order: it is greater than half the elements, and less than the other half.  The 50th percentile is greater than 50% of the elements, and less than the other 50%.  Yes, they're the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`DescriptiveStatistics.getPercentile`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html#getPercentile%28double%29)

The 50th percentile is, by definition, the median.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Math is like a hurricane, so one has to check for the version he is going to mention. I am using the v3.6.1 now, and it includes [Median](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/rank/Median.html) (a Percentile override with fixed quantile = 50) and [Percentile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/rank/Percentile.html) classes.